# How to create a copy of database tables into another computer

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I have some table in the test database. How to create a copy of the tables into another computer ?

Comment: Did that work? I'm not at my PC.

Comment: Backup & restore ?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to make a copy of all the tables along with the data present in my database of "computer A" into the database of "computer B".

1. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio > Connect.
2. Right Click on The database which has the tables > Tasks > Generate Scripts.
3. Select either full database Specific table > Next
4. Advanced > Scroll down to "Types of Data to Script" and select "Schema and Data". > OK
5. Select location to save Script
6. Next > Next > Finish.

Now copy This Script File into "computer B"

1. Double click will open it into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
2. Click "Execute" button from top toolbar.

Done, Just Refresh the database and all your tables with the data are now copied.

Answer (score 0):

For some objects,  Do tasks, copy database objects, in ssms

If you want to copy whole database, 
Do backup database, then do restore on target machine

Comment: there in no "copy database" in tools menu.

Comment: There is one copy database option if I right lick on database > tasks. But that wizard doesn't give any option to make a copy of database like file.

Comment: I have created a backup file using, Right click on database > tasks > backup. Tomorrow i will try to restore it in another machine n see if that work.

Answer (score -1):

You can copy the relevant .mdf files from SQL server Installation folder(C:\Program Files \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.10\MSSQL\Data) to other 
computer's SQL server Installation folder

Then you can attach those mdf files using SQL Server Management Studio

1) In object explorer, right click on "Databases" and click on attach

2) Click on "Add button"

3) Then select copied mdf files from the SQL server Installation folder

4) Then click OK